# Why the python class method is different with it's object method but both of them have the same id?

Tags: python, class, methods

While I'm studying the [python attributes and methods](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html), and read to the *Example 1.2. A function is more*. I try to do a simple test base on the example, but the result makes me a little confused.

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     def fun(self):
...         pass
...     
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.fun is foo.fun
False
>>> id(f.fun) 
36093064
>>> id(foo.fun)
36093064
>>>
```

python version, 2.7.5
operation sys, win8

Why the 'is' test return False but the id return the same value? I expected to see the difference ids in the beginning. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: More info about this: https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-30/methods-are-objects-bound-or

Comment: The reason why the IDs are the same is this: After you have checked the ID of `f.fun`, the object gets deleted. The object `foo.fun` then gets put into the *same place in memory* that `f.fun` used to be in. You can prevent this by keeping variables that reference the objects: With `a = f.fun; b = foo.fun; print id(a), id(b)` you get two different IDs.

Comment: @badc0re Thank you, I will read it.

Comment: @flornquake Thank you, the scripts a = f.fun; b = foo.fun; print id(a), id(b) make things more clearly.

Answer (score 5):

What the `id` is is an internal implementation detail. The `id` is of little use to use as a programmer. In CPython it tends to be the memory address of the object, the object in this case being a function object.

In this case the object is the same, it's a function. In one case the function is bound to an instance, in the other case it's not. This means that when you call it, in the bound case it will automatically get the instance as the first parameter, and in the second case not.

But it is the same function.

So why does `f.fun is foo.fun` return `False`?

Because methods compare as not being the same. Even with themselves:

```
 >>> foo.fun is foo.fun
 False
 >>> f = foo()
 >>> f.fun is f.fun
 False
```

This is because these objects are wrappers. If you want to compare methods, compare the im_func attribute:

```
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar.fun.im_func is foo.fun.im_func
True
>>> f.fun.im_func is foo.fun.im_func
True
```

In Python 3, the unbound method is gone, and normal functions are used. So in Python 3 you will get:

```
>>> foo.fun is foo.fun
True
```

Bound methods still compare as false to themselves:

```
>>> f.fun is f.fun
False
```

And you need to compare using the `__func__` attribute:

```
>>> f.fun.__func__ is foo.fun
True
```

Comment: @thefourtheye: Using for 14 years helps.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Thanks a lot! How could I learn the python internal details like you guys?

Comment: @Erxin: Try to figure out the answer to Stackoverflow questions you don't already know the answer to is actually a pretty good way. Using Python for a long time also works (but is slow). You can also try to fix bugs in Python itself.

Comment: @LennartRegebro OK, I will try to follow your suggestions. :)